# ruby on rails rest client gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, rest-client

Hi I'm trying to make a post request to an api using the rest client gem. The site has posted an example request as follows:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"email": "email@example.com", "password": "password"}' -X POST "http://example.com/users"
```

My post route in the user controller is:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  require 'rest_client'

  def index
    post = RestClient.post 'http://example.com/users', { 'email' => 'test@test.com', 'password'=>'testing1234' }
  end

end
```

All I get is a `400 Bad Request error`. I just want to make the request to get a response. Any help on syntax would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you making the request to `http://example.com/users`?

Comment: No, I am just using this as an example site. The urls follow the same format.

Comment: You need to set the headers to `application_json`. The answer from Sergio should be ok.

Comment: unfortunately that did not work, when I try :content_type => 'application/json' I get a bad request. When I try :content_type => 'application_json' I get a 500 internal server error.

Comment: I got it! The params for the email is not in quotes. {"email": email@example.com, "password": password}. Thanks for your help